# protractor microsoft single sign on Automation

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor, single-sign-on

I have a web page where I have a log in button. Once I click on the Login Button it takes me to Microsoft single sign-on screen, Where I give my username and password, But I have two-factor authorisation enabled too where a code is received in my registered mobile.

I am not sure how can I automate this and all the functionality sits inside this login page.

How can I automate this in protractor, Could not find any resource to achieve this!!

Comment: Basically, you can't unless you disable 2fa. The option I have used before is to have a separate login page that can be used only for the e2e tests. We only used that page for dev and qa environments and made sure the page is not accessible in production. Is the code stored anywhere? If so, can you get access to it? Can you change where the code is being sent? Meaning, can you send it to an email address instead of a sms message to a phone? If you can send it to an email, you can probably pull the code out of the email with some regex. If not, there really aren't many options to automate this.

Comment: @tehbeardedone thanks for the suggestion. I guess I have to take your suggested approach to have a separate login page for e2e testing. I am not sure why I did not think about this earlier.. Thanks for the suggestion.